# What language/character set is this?

Tags: utf-8, character, set, hebrew, latin

I've been given this data thats actually been translated from hebrew character and they've come out like this? Im guessing something todo with character sets or something. but could someone tell me what this actually is please? or translate it into something interesting.

thanks

```
% D7% 92% D7% A8% D7% A1% D7% 94% 20% D7% A1% D7% 99% D7% A0% D7% 99% D7% AA% 20% D7% 9B% D7% AA% D7 % 95% D7% A6% D7% 90% D7% 94% 20% D7% 99% D7% A4% D7% A0% D7% 99% D7% AA% 20 [bwbwlnw% 20 []],% 20 &?% 20quot?% 20% D7% 9B% D7% 93% D7% 99% 20% D7% 9C% D7% 94% D7% A9% D7% AA% D7% 9E% D7% A9,% 20 [[% D7% 9B% D7% 9E% D7% 95% 20% D7% 96% D7% 94% 20krksss% 20% D7% 96% D7% 94]],% 20% D7% A2% D7% 9D% 20% D7% AA % D7% 99% D7% 90% D7% 95% D7% A8% 20% D7% 94% D7% 90% D7% 97% D7% 95% D7% A8% D7% 99% 20% D7% 91% D7 % A9% D7% 91% D7% 95% D7% A2% 20% D7% 91% D7% 90% D7% 96% D7% 95% D7% A8% 20% D7% 94% D7% AA% D7% A9 % D7% 9C% D7% 95% D7% 9D% 20% D7% 97% D7% A8% D7% 93% D7% 94% 20% D7% 9B% D7% 90% D7% A9% D7% A8% 20% D7% 94% D7% 9C% D7% A7% D7% 95% D7% 97% 20% D7% A9% D7% 9C% 20% D7% 94% D7% 99% D7% 95% D7% 9D% 20abbwrtthynyty% 20% D7% 94% D7% 92% D7% A0% D7% 90% D7% 9C% D7% 95% D7% 92% D7% 99% D7% 94% 20% D7% 9E% D7% A7% D7% 91% D7% 9C% 20% D7% A8% D7% 98% D7% 95% D7% 91% 20% D7% 90% D7% 99% D7% A4% D7% A9% D7% 94% D7% 95,% 20 []]% 20% D7% 94% D7% 9E% D7% 9C% D7% 90% D7% 9A% 20% D7% A9% D7% 9C% 20% D7% 94% D7% 9E% D7% 91% D7% 95% D7% 90% 20% D7% A0% D7% 98% D7% 95% 20% D7% A9% D7% 9C% 20% D7% A9% D7% 9E% D7% 97% D7% 94% 20% D7% 94% D7% 94% D7% 92% D7% 94% 20 [[[[]% 20fsbwlwkhnt% 20])% 20 []% 20aaldaaxl% 20% D7% 9B% D7% AA % D7% 95% D7% A6% D7% 90% D7% 94% 20awkwmblktwftt,% 20% D7% 94% D7% A2% D7% A0% D7% 99% D7% 99% D7% 9F% 20% D7% 94% D7% 9B% D7% 99% 20% D7% 9E% D7% AA% D7% 90% D7% 99% D7% 9D% 20% D7% 9E% D7% A9% D7% 95% D7% 95% D7% 94% 20% D7% A2% D7% 9D% 20% D7% 90% D7% AA% D7% 94% 20% D7% 9E% D7% 90% D7% 9E% D7% A5% D7% 20% A7% D7% 98% D7% 9F% 20% D7% 9E% D7% 90% D7% 95% D7% 93,% 20 [[[&?% 20 #% 2039 ]]],% 20% D7% 92 % D7% 95% D7% A8% D7% 9E% D7% AA% 20% D7% 9C% D7% AA% D7% A4% D7% A7% D7% 95% D7% 93% 20 []% 20% D7 % 9C% D7% A9% D7% 95% D7% A7% 20wsjjlt% 20% D7% 90% D7% 95% D7% 91% D7% 99% D7% 99% D7% A7% D7% 98,% 20% D7% 95% D7% 96% D7% 94% 20% D7% 9C% D7% 90% 20% D7% 94% D7% A9% D7% 9C% D7% 99% D7% 9E% D7% 94% 20% D7% 94% D7% 99% D7% 90% 20alcangue% 20% D7% 99% D7% 93% D7% 95% D7% A2,% 20% D7% 9C% D7% A4% D7% 99% 20% D7 % 94% D7% A1% D7% 93% D7% A8,% 20% D7% 96% D7% 94% 20% D7% 99% D7% 95% D7% A8% D7% 93.% 20% D7% 94 % D7% 9E% D7% 93% D7% 95% D7% 91% D7% A8% 20% D7% 9C% D7% 9E% D7% 9C% D7% 90% 20% D7% 94% D7% A9% D7 % 99% D7% A8% 20% D7% 94% D7% 9E% D7% A6% D7% 91% 20% D7% A6% D7% 95% D7% A7% 20% D7% 94% D7% 94% D7 % A4% D7% A8% D7% 93% D7% 94% 2010% 20% D7% 9B% D7% 9C% 20% D7% 94% D7% A0% D7% 95% D7% A9% D7% 90% 20 % D7% 92% D7% 9C% D7% 99% D7% 9C,% 20% D7% 91% 20% D7% A4% D7% 92% D7% 9D% 20% D7% A7% D7% 9C% 20% D7% 95% D7% 94% D7% 95% D7% 90% 20% D7% A0% D7% 9E% D7% A6% D7% 90% 20% D7% AA% D7% 97% D7% AA% 20% D7% 94% D7% A8% D7% 90% D7% A9% 20% D7% 91% D7% A0% D7% 99% D7% A1% D7% 99% D7% 95% D7% 9F% 20% D7% 90% D7% A9% D7% A8% 20% D7% A9% D7% 9C% D7% 95% 20% D7% 94% D7% 95% D7% 90% 20% D7% 92% D7% 9C% D7% 99% D7% 93% D7% 94% 20% D7% 9C% D7% 90% 20% D7% A0% D7% 99% D7% AA% D7% 9F% 20% D7% 9C% D7% A0% D7 % 95% 20% D7% 9C% D7% A7% D7% 99% D7% 99% D7% 9D% 20% D7% A9% D7% 9C% D7% A0% D7% 95% 20% D7% 9C% D7 % A0% D7% 95% 20% D7% 9B% D7% 99% 20% D7% 91% D7% 90% D7% 96% D7% 95% D7% A8% 20 [[twwGshG]]% 20% D7% 94% D7% 90% D7% 97% D7% 95% D7% A8% D7% 99% 20% D7% 95% D7% 90% D7% AA% D7% 20% 96% D7% 94% 20% D7% 9C% D7% 97% D7% 9C% D7% A5.% 20 &?% 20quot?
```

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely Hebrew, I can make out some of it, but the encoding is garbled.  Removing all the extra spaces and some other characters, I got:

```
%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%94%20%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%20%20%20%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A9%20%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%95%20%D7%96%D7%94%20%20%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%97%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%20%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9A%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%94%D7%92%D7%94%20%20%20%20%20%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%94%20%20%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94%20%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A5%D7%20%A7%D7%98%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%93%20%20%20%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%20%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A7%20%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%98%20%D7%95%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%90%20%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2%20%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8%20%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%93%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%91%20%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A7%20%D7%94%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%94%2010%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%90%20%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%91%20%D7%A4%D7%92%D7%9D%20%D7%A7%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%A0%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%90%20%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A8%20%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%20%96%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A5%20%20
```

The start is:

```
גרסה סינית כתוצאה יפנית   כדי להשתמש כמו זה  זה עם תיאור האחורי בשבוע באזור התשלום חרדה כאשר הלקוח של היום  הגנאלוגיה מקבל רטוב איפשהו  המלאך של המבוא נטו של שמחה ההגה     כתוצאה
```

Which means (my translation):

Chinese version as a Japanese result   so as to use like this   This with backward description in the area of the payment worried that the customer of the day  the geneology get wet somewhere  the angel of the introduction of happiness of pronunciation

Answer (score 1):

[I believe this table should help](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/hebrew.html)

Knowing that it is hebrew and that the 05 is added everywhere it should be these characters...

Comment: because they use the marks around the letters some of these are not actual letters but the marks - for example Dח7 is Het and 92 (segol) will be three dots above the letter

Answer (score 0):

Google translate says `As Chinese Remove D7 Japanese [bwbwlnw []], &? quot? To use, [[like this krksss it]], with a description of the payment in the week back in fear when the customer of today abbwrtthynyty somewhere genealogy gets wet, []] the angel of the net introduction of joy wheel [[[[] fsbwlwkhnt]) [] aaldaaxl As awkwmblktwftt, it compares with the best fit you very Satan effort, [[[&? # 39]]], causes the function [] market wsjjlt object, which is not completed is alcangue known, in order, it goes down. The song in question to fill the separation cliff situation all the subject cylinder 10, in slight defect and is under his head in an attempt which is not possible to have ice cream to us that in our [[twwGshG]] back and the extract. &? quot?`

Answer (score 0):

try php function urldecode - urldecode — Decodes URL-encoded string
$data = urldecode($your_string);
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php